# Getting date difference in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to get date difference between today and expiring day. This is the code I implemented. But this is not returning the right output.

```
public String[] getDaysList(){
    Cursor cursor = db.query("COUPON", null, null, null, null, null, null );
    if(cursor.getCount()<1){
        cursor.close();
        return null;
    }
    String[] array = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    int i=0;
    while(cursor.moveToNext()){

        String days = "(julianday('now') - julianday(EXPIRED_DATE))";
        array[i] = days;
        i++;
    }
    return array;
}
```

This returns `(julianday('now') - julianday(EXPIRED_DATE))`. Please help me to get date difference as string to a array here.

Answer (score 1):

The `now` modifier returns not only the date but also the time.

To change the timestamp to the start of the date, use the [date() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```sql
SELECT julianday(date('now')) - julianday(EXPIRED_DATE) FROM ...
```

(If the expired column also contains time values, you have to use `date()` for it, too.)

And to actually execute this, you have to give it to the database:

```java
public String[] getDaysList() {
    String days = "julianday(date('now')) - julianday("+EXPIRED_DATE+")";
    Cursor cursor = db.query("COUPON",
                             new String[]{ days },  // query returns one column
                             null, null, null, null, null);
    try {
        String[] array = new String[cursor.getCount()];
        int i = 0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            array[i++] = cursor.getString(0);       // read this column
        }
        return array.length > 0 ? array : null;
    } finally {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

(And the number of days is not a string; consider using `int[]` instead.)

Answer (score 0):

Hi please try these one

```
    Cursor  cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT julianday('now') - julianday(DateCreated) FROM COUPON", null);

 if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                   array[i]=cursor.getString(0)
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            }
```

Comment: No of days shows as `18.4855` but actual days are `18`. How to fix decimal places.